# What is the relation between the wave function in Born's rule and the wave function in Dirac's equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, quantum-spin, dirac-equation, born-rule

The wave function for spins without position can be seen as a complex wave vector $\psi=(\psi_1,\psi_2,\ldots)$ and the probability to measure a state $\psi^{(A)}$ in another state $\psi^{(B)}$ is
$$
P=|\langle\psi^{(A)}|\psi^{(B)}\rangle|^2
$$
The relativistic Dirac wave equation is
$$
i\hbar \gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\Psi-mc\Psi=0
$$
where gamma matrices appear.

What is the relation between both concepts $\psi$ and $\Psi$? Can I use Born's rule on the relativistic wave function somehow?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/648202